# ExtJS 4 - please explain Model & Store

Tags: model, extjs4, store, extjs-mvc

I am trying to get my head round what appears to be the simplest of things:

I want to load a collection of objects via a JSON-returning server-side call,

why do all these return something unexpected?

```
> modelStore.data.items[0].Id
undefined
> modelStore.data.items[0].getId()
undefined
> modelStore.data.items[0].getTitle()
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTitle'
> modelStore.getById(1)
null
> modelStore.getTotalCount()
1
> modelStore.first()
Ext.Class.newClass < should be PegModel??
```

**The code:**

```
Ext.define('PegfileApp.model.PegModel', {

  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

  fields: ['Id', 'Title'],

  //hasMany: {model: 'RootDimension', name: 'rootDimensions'},

  proxy:
  {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'PegModel',
    timeout: 120000,
    noCache: false,
    reader:
    {
      root: 'PegModel',
      successProperty: 'success'
    }
  }
});

Ext.define('PegfileApp.store.PegModels', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  model: 'PegfileApp.model.PegModel',
  autoLoad: true,
  autoSync: false,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'PegModel',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'PegModels',
      successProperty: 'success'
    }
  }
});
```

**The data:**

```
{"PegModels":[{"Title":"PegModel","Id":1}],"success":true}
```

I understood for each property defined on the Model, we have a corresponding getter: get{PropertyName}()?

Do i need to cast the "Record" somehow to a "Model"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. :)

Store has array of models but you don't access them directly via `items[]`. You use `store.getAt(index)` method instead if `store.items[index]` for example.

Also check out `store.find()` method and similar to it to get an idea how to get that index for particular record.

Once you got record which will be model instance you use `record.get('fieldname')` to get different fields.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work yes, but seems counter intuitive given when you create an instance of the Model you have these getters at your disposal. What about associations? The docs talk about e.g. user.products() where products is an association defined on the Model, but is it defined on the record?

Comment: I haven't used much of associations... But yes, I think getters for them will be automatically defined in the model.

Comment: im getting confused between creating an instance of a Model and retrieving a record from a Store, they are not the same thing?

Comment: When you create an instance of a model - it's basically record which is not attached to the store yet. You need to do `store.add(record)` to add it to the store. And when you retrieve it from the store using `getAt()` you're getting reference to the record already in the store.

Comment: but getTitle() works when its an instance of a model but not when used from store.getAt(0) :S

Comment: well... don't use getTitle() use get('title') :)  I don't think retrieving fields using getXXXX is officially supported and documented way

Answer (score 1):

Realize this is an old post but this still comes up a lot even today. To simplify, consider Model an object and Store an array. A Store is an array of objects. Sometimes you'll work with just an object. Other times you want to work with a collection of objects. Libraries such as Ext extend these "objects" and "arrays" with methods that allow you to operate on them more conveniently.